# How do I make the script remember the candle change in real time despite its subsequent changes?

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5

I want to mark bearish candles in real time, the high of which turned out to be two times more than the gap between the opening and closing price of the candle. My script fixes such a change and makes a plotshape, but as soon as the candle changes its size in real time again, the plotshopa pattern disappears. How do I make it so that it remembers the change of the candle in real time despite its subsequent changes?

```
redCandle = (close < open)

distance_from_high_to _lose = high - open

candle_body = open - close

up = redCandle and distance_from_high_to _lose> candly_body * 2

plotshape(series = up, title = "Oversold", location = location.belowbar, color = color.green, textcolor = color.green, style = shape.triangleup, text = "Buy")
```